# end of line error with classic asp

Tags: syntax, asp-classic

I have a do a project for school with classic asp which I ave never used before.

I keep getting this syntax error:

```
Expected end of statement
set Y=server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");
---------------------------------------------^
```

The asp code i'm trying to execute is:

```
<%
set Y=server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
X = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ= " & Server.MapPath(".\account.mdb")Y.open X

user=request.Form("username")
set useraccount=Y.Execute("select * from logintable where username='" & user & "'")

if useraccount.eof then
    Response.Redirect("41697hw1noaccount.htm");
else if useraccount.fields[0].passwd == request.Form("pwd") then
    Response.Redirect("41697hw1wrongpasswd.htm")
else
    Response.Write("<h1>Welcome, " & useraccount.fields[0].fullname & "</h1>")
end if

%>
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: VB-Script does not take semi-colons to terminate the lines. If you are new to vbscript I would suggest turning on OPTION EXPLICIT as it help catch some typos.

Comment: Why is that not on by default! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with VBScript, but I think you should not put a ';' at the end of your statement. I think removing the semi-colon will help.

Comment: yup vbscript does not have an end of line terminator however if you want to span lines you need to use and underscore _

Comment: And it you want to put two statements on a single line you can use a semi-colon :

Comment: I believe as commented below that this is the wrong answer? [How to: Break and Combine Statements in Code (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ba9sxbw4.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

In vbscript the explicit "end-of-line " character is a colon ":"

It is not required in vbscript unless you want to put more than one statement on a physical line.

for example--

Dim myVariable : myVariable = "some string"

Comment: So in actual fact the one marked as the answer here is incorrect? - [How to: Break and Combine Statements in Code (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ba9sxbw4.aspx)